# May I exchange leave for money

Tags: professionalism

My leave is coming up in December but I don't want to take it. I want to ask the company to pay me leave pay instead of giving me leave days. Are the company allowed to refuse my request?

Comment: Welcome to The Workplace.  We can't answer questions about laws (depends on where you live, and we're not lawyers) or about the policies of a particular company.  However, if you were to ask instead how you can go about making this request (how to pitch it, etc), that would be on-topic for us.  When you [edit] your question it will automatically be put in the review queue for possible reopening.  Thanks.

Comment: A simple way to think about this - what do you think you would say if your company asked you to take more leave, in return for less money?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to read your employment contract. Some companies have "use it or lose it" policies where you lose the vacation if you do not take it. Others (like my old company) have a policy where they pay you for any vacation time you did not use for the year. Others have both (pay you for up to two unused weeks and lose anything after that, for example).

Comment: Others have a policy where you can move some days to the next year. For example five days to be used up to end of March; in one case I had "unlimited as long as the holiday starts in the previous year" so you could take all your annual holiday starting on December 31st if you wished to do so.